# How to update only one input in Laravel form?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

working with laravel and mysql. I have user update form with `name`,`email`,`password` and `conform password` with following controller validation,

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'name' =>'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'sometimes|min:6|confirmed'
  ]);
```

in my form normaly users do not update this all input fields. as an example some user need update only email. but with above validation when we update only name or email validation display message `The password must be at least 6 characters.` then how can do only name or email update without password update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'name' =>'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
  ]);

  $name  = $request->name ;
  $email = $request->email;
  $q = User::where('id','=',auth()->user()->id);
  $q->update(['name'=>$name,'email'=>$email]);

  if(isset($request->password)){
       $this->validate($request,[
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
       ]);
       $password = $request->password);
       $q->update(['password'=>$password );
  }
```

Also you can do it by putting changing password in seperate form.

Answer (score 0):

Use if condition. When a user submit the form check which fields are empty and which are not. If field is empty then user don't want to update that info and you don't need to run the validation for that field.I am not expert in laravel so i can't post any demo code. But i have used this approach in other frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email',
]);

$validator->sometimes('password', 'min:6|confirmed', function ($input) {
    return $input->password;
});

if(!$validator->fails()){
    ...
}
```

I am not sure about `return $input->password`. I suppose, you should use `return !empty($input->password)`.

When password is null, then don't apply the rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify, the `password` is only required when `password_confirmation` has value and conversely `password_confirmation` is only required when `password` as a value

```
'name'                  => 'required',
'email'                 => 'required|email',
'password'              => 'required_with:password_confirmation|min:6|confirmed',
'password_confirmation' => 'required_with:password',
```

With this scenario, you can update the name, email AND keeping the password empty. (Don't forget to check when you update the user)

In case the user fill the password, it will needs to be confirmed with minimum 6 chars

Comment: this is got same results

Comment: I'm using this on my projects and it works just fine. `<input name="password" type="password">` must be empty when you load the page and as I said, when you update the user, if password is empty you don't update the field password `$input =  $request->except('password`);` else `$input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$requestKeys = $request->keys();
$rules = array_filter([
    'name' =>'required',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'sometimes|min:6|confirmed'
], static function($value, $key) use ($requestKeys){
    return in_array($key, $requestKeys, true);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
$this->validate($request, $rules);
```

Will left only sended fields. But i use custom requests, also i have Abstract base request, which contains method like this.