# Update File Upload on Laravel 6

Tags: html, laravel

I have a edit form , and this edit form is can changes files upload .
i can show this file . but on store function update is not work properly . **only file cant updated .**

its my store function

```
 public function update_pelatihan(Request $request, $id)
{



    $pelatihan = Master_seminar_pelatihan::find($id);

    $pelatihan->nama_pelatihan       = $request->input('nama_pelatihan') ;
    $pelatihan->nomor_pelatihan      = $request->input('nomor_pelatihan') ;
    $pelatihan->tanggal              = $request->input('tanggal') ;
    $pelatihan->uraian               = $request->input('uraian') ;
    $pelatihan->tempat               = $request->input('tempat') ;


    if($request->hasfile('file_scan'))

    {   
    $file = $request->file('file_scan');

        $extension = $request->file_scan->getClientOriginalExtension();  //Get Image Extension
        $fileName =  uniqid().'.'.$extension;  //Concatenate both to get FileName (eg: file.jpg)
        $file->move(public_path().'/file_pelatihan/', $fileName);  
        $data = $fileName; 
        $pelatihan->update(['file_scan'=>$data]);
    }



    dd($pelatihan);
    //$pelatihan->save();
    //return redirect ('pelatihan')->with('success', 'Input Succes');


}
```

i try to update 2 data . but this file cant be updated ,

```
    Master_seminar_pelatihan {#503 ▼

  #attributes: array:10 [▼
    "id" => 18
    "user_id" => 35
    "nama_pelatihan" => "Pelatihan Keperawatan Keempat"
    "nomor_pelatihan" => "89238245"
    "tanggal" => "2019-11-26"
    "uraian" => "Pelatihan Tentang"
    "tempat" => "Solo Jawa Tengah"
    "file_scan" => "5ddc90ca5b607.pdf"
    "created_at" => "2019-11-26 02:41:14"
    "updated_at" => "2019-11-27 02:31:24"
  ]
  #original: array:10 [▼
    "id" => 18
    "user_id" => 35
    "nama_pelatihan" => "Pelatihan Keperawatan Keempat"
    "nomor_pelatihan" => "89238245"
    "tanggal" => "2019-11-26"
    "uraian" => "Pelatihan Tentang"
    "tempat" => "Solo Jawa Tengah"
    "file_scan" => "5ddc90ca5b607.pdf"
    "created_at" => "2019-11-26 02:41:14"
    "updated_at" => "2019-11-27 02:31:24"
  ]
  #changes: array:2 [▼
    "nomor_pelatihan" => "89238245"
    "updated_at" => "2019-11-27 02:31:24"
  ]
```

whats wrong on my store function ?

i create this update file from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53756328/how-to-update-only-one-input-in-laravel-form)

Answer (score -1):

iam sorry its solved . :((((((((((((((((((((((((((((((

i just changed

```
public function update_pelatihan(Request $request, $id)
{



    $pelatihan = Master_seminar_pelatihan::find($id);

    $pelatihan->nama_pelatihan       = $request->input('nama_pelatihan') ;
    $pelatihan->nomor_pelatihan      = $request->input('nomor_pelatihan') ;
    $pelatihan->tanggal              = $request->input('tanggal') ;
    $pelatihan->uraian               = $request->input('uraian') ;
    $pelatihan->tempat               = $request->input('tempat') ;


    if($request->hasfile('file_scan'))

    {   
    $file = $request->file('file_scan');

        $extension = $request->file_scan->getClientOriginalExtension();  //Get Image Extension
        $fileName =  uniqid().'.'.$extension;  //Concatenate both to get FileName (eg: file.jpg)
        $file->move(public_path().'/file_pelatihan/', $fileName);  
        $data = $fileName; 
        $pelatihan->file_scan = $data;
    }



   // dd($pelatihan);
    $pelatihan->save();
    return redirect ('pelatihan')->with('success', 'Input Succes');


}
```

Comment: If you are writing this as an answer, could you write the solution here instead of 'it is solved' so anyone with a similar problem will know how to fix it